# Is it possible to make a Java lambda expression when String is truncated by 2 characters to make a set?

Tags: java, lambda

Strings are split by two characters to form elements of a multiple set. At this time, only the letter pairs of English characters are valid, and if other spaces, numbers, or special characters are included, the letter pair is discarded. For example, if "ab+" is input, only "ab" is taken as an element of the multiset, and "b+" is discarded.
When comparing between multiple set elements, differences between uppercase and lowercase letters are ignored. "AB", "Ab", and "ab" are treated as the same element.

I want to make the top part a lambda each.

```
ArrayList<String> aryChars1 = new ArrayList<String>();      
        
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]";
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length() - 1; i++)
{
    if (Pattern.matches(pattern, str1.substring(i, i+1))) {
        aryChars1.add(str1.substring(i, i+2));
    }
                
}
```

Comment: “Split” has a specific meaning with strings.  I suspect you mean something different.  It appears you are supposed to add every sequence of two letters in the input string to a Set, which doesn’t involve a split operation at all.  Is that correct?

Comment: What does *"make the top part a lambda each"* mean? Do you mean you want to use Stream? Which "top part" are you referring to? The code before the loop? The loop itself? The code inside the loop? How would that classify as "top part", when it's the last part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks if the first of a 2-character set is a letter, so e.g. `"b+"` is *not* discarded.

For better performance, you should only compile the regex pattern once.

Since you want to use lambda, I would do it like this:

```java
String str1 = "Hello World";

List<String> aryChars1 = Pattern.compile("(?=([a-zA-Z]{2})).")
        .matcher(str1).results()
        .map(m -> m.group(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(aryChars1);
```

*Output*

```
[He, el, ll, lo, Wo, or, rl, ld]
```

As you can see, the `"o "` pair is discarded.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a dot - `.` - at the end of the pattern string. From my test, you get the same result if you remove it.

Comment: @Abra That's true, it can be removed.

Comment: thank you.
Efficiency is not considered at all.
I asked a question because I didn't know if this was possible while studying the lambda expression.